# Insert data to Mysql about Viewers Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Have some question.

I need table with data about my visitors. I have This Schema :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('viewers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->primary('id');
            $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
            $table->string('country')->nullable();
            $table->string('city')->nullable();
            $table->text('device')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('last_activity')->useCurrent();
            $table->rememberToken();
        });
    }
```

That's my Controller in my page.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $viewer = New Viewers();

    $data = \Stevebauman\Location\Facades\Location::get('83.143.245.162');

    $viewer->ip_address = $request->ip();
    $viewer->country = $data->countryName;
    $viewer->city = $data->cityName;
    $viewer->device = $request->userAgent();

    $viewer->save();
}
```

That's my Error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `viewers` (`ip_address`, `country`, `city`, `device`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (::1, Germany, Frankfurt am Main, Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.1 Safari/605.1.15, 2020-11-26 10:11:06, 2020-11-26 10:11:06))
```

Why `updated_at, created_at` trying to inserting into table??

Comment: It probably expects those columns to be there by default, and if they're not it needs to know. How did you create the table? Did you remove something in the default migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's default Laravel feature, Laravel would try to automatically fill in created_at/updated_at and wouldn’t find them.

If you do not want those two column in your `Viewers` model, add following line.

```
 public $timestamps = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 2):

By default all models on laravel has updated_at and created_at. If your table dont have it you should disable it by adding `public $timestamps = false;` on the model.

```
class Viewers extends Model
{
   public $timestamps = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `$table->timestamps()` in your migration

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('viewers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->primary('id');
        $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
        $table->string('country')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
        $table->text('device')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('last_activity')->useCurrent();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();    //for created_at and updated_at columns
    });
}
```

And if you don't want `updated_at` and `created_at` columns

```php
class Viewer extends Model
{
//In Model class set timestamps to false
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```